# Is turning a device on/off by using it power cord more harmful than using its on/off button?

Tags: best-practice

Is it potentially harmful to the user or the longevity of a device to turn it on/off by using its power cord or a controllable power switch rather than its on/off button? If it depends on the device, how so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple device, the power cord or a powerline switch would be OK. But for many types of processor based device, its own on/off button is not a mains switch but a signal to the processor, allowing it to do an orderly shutdown.

If you pulled the plug on your PC every night it would soon lose chunks of its filesystem, and hard drives from a former era could physically destroy themselves if their heads weren't properly parked before power was removed.

One of the quickest ways to destroy an Epson inkjet printer was to power it down this way, with the print head uncapped and liable to dry out, instead of allowing it to cap its ink reservoir first.

So there are cases where a device's own power switch is the best option.

On the other hand, I remember a floor-standing 14" disk drive with a massive 20MB per platter, whose power switch was woefully underrated for its spindle motor; switching off the power switch would occasionally leave its contacts welded together, and a horsepower motor running as if nothing had happened. You quickly learned to use the breaker under the machine round the back instead.

Comment: Very good points about terminating execution and entering a safe sleeping state. What about wear merely due to an increased frequency of being turned on/off?

Comment: Again that would very much depend on the individual appliance. Soft start circuits can reduce wear; however, it is possible to design soft starters that work however power is applied, and that is clearly safer than relying on a specific way of starting, in the presence of power fails for example. So I would expect few appliances to have problems with external switching.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that which option is better, if at all, is heavily dependent on the circuit; but if we had to think of a general rule I imagine that by leaving mains plugged in when trying to shut a system down could still at least leave a path to mains/earth ground for residual charges to dissipate into instead of a floating ground. I say this is dependent on the circuit because if the switch closed the path to ground, then there isn't really a difference in doing either.

Comment: So using a switch on a power strip is probably better than pulling the cable.

Comment: @Emre not for computerized devices. Always use the devices power switch when available.

Comment: @Passerby: So you disagree with Jon, or do you mean that they are equal? The reason I posed this question is that I am considering using networked power switches that will remotely turn devices on and off.

Comment: @Emre the static/floating ground issue is different from the issues that cutting power to a computerized device would cause. Like Brian's answer posts, there are problems if you turn off a computer mid-write or before it saves changes to it's disk. And that applies to anything from computers to routers, newer tvs, cable boxes. Things with flash drives are just as bad as hard drives.